# include enabled/disabled account status of LDAP User in results

Tags: active-directory

When running a ldap search query, I want to return the status of the user within the results. i.e. include a attribute which identifies if the user account is disabled.

this is the filter I am using:

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
```

I've seen examples which allow you to filter out disabled accounts, but I want to return both enabled and disabled accounts but with a flag to identify this status. is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found the answer  if you do a bitwise

```
(userAccountControl & 2) != 0) // disabled
```